# Next issue - SuiteCRM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, bitnami, suitecrm

So I spent the last week or so trying to configure this. I have MariaDB/SkySql on the back end, hosted on GCP, launching a SuiteCRM instance from GCP via Bitnami. Finally believe I have it set up so it's hitting the MariaDB database (had to edit the config.php and the MysqliManager.php files to get that to work). However, now it's not letting me set up a user to even sign in. I get to the sign in screen, but none work. I have done a full restore of a database instance of SuiteCRM tables to the Maria database. I have also tried the suggestion out there to set the password hash.. and nothing is working. From SSH I can confirm that I have access to the database, so I am fairly sure I'm hitting the right database, either that or it somehow resorted back to the localhost instance. Config.php still shows the MariaDB instance though.

In the config I also set the ability to reset password, and even though I have a user, email_bean, Email address set up - it's not recognizing the user or password, which is making me wonder if the database connection still isn't right!

Anyone ever set up SuiteCRM through GCP (or I suppose AWS may have similar issues) and a different database backend and make it work?

Comment: Hi! As you have performed modifications to the `MysqliManager.php` file (that handles the connection to the DB), it might be possible that the errors you are facing are produced by those changes. My suggestion was to restore this file, and indeed it seemed to work! More information here: https://community.bitnami.com/t/suitecrm-connection-to-mariadb/94499/11?u=jcarmona

Answer (score 0):

Restore the changes you have made to the MysqliManager.php file.

Use the documentation below to restore the file:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/suitecrm/administration/backup-restore-mysql-mariadb/